# C# Dynamics: Convert.ChangeType versus Cast

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, casting, type-conversion

Could someone explain why casting a dynamic object as a class returns that class while using Convert.ChangeType returns a dynamic object, particularly at runtime?  For instance:

```
 dynamic dObject = new SomeClass();
 var dTest1 = dObject as SomeClass;                           // returns SomeClass
 var dTest2 = Convert.ChangeType(dObject, typeof(SomeClass)); // returns dynamic
```

The broader problem: I have a series of helper classes which implement a generic interface.  I need to pass a list of these classes around to other objects; however the different helper classes use different types for the generic parameter, so I cannot pass a list of the helper classes directly:

```
interface IHelper<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Foo();
}
var HelperList = new List<IHelper<T>> // Can't do this because T varies from helper to helper!
```

So I thought I could fake out the runtime by creating a container class which contains the helper class and the generic type, but leverages dynamics:

```
class ContainerClass
{
    IHelper<dynamic> HelperClass;
    Type dType;                      // Specifies the type for the dynamic object
}
```

Now I can create and pass a List of ContainerClass around.  All the processing works great until I need to assign the results from Foo() back to the destination IEnumerables, at which point I get runtime errors saying that type object cannot be converted to such and such concrete class, even though the unboxed object types match those required.  If I attempt similar syntax as in dTest2 above, the runtime is still unable to figure out the "conversion".

I realize this is probably an abuse of dynamic and poor programming practice to boot.  I will certainly use a different solution if and when I can identify one, but for now I either need to make this work or go with something less ambitious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At execution time, there's no such thing as `dynamic` really.

However, the call to `Convert.ChangeType` is providing a `dynamic` value as an argument. *Any* method call using a `dynamic` argument is treated as having a return value of `dynamic`, because the compiler doesn't know what the actual signature will be until execution time.

However, if you use a cast, an `is` or an `as` expression, or a constructor call there's only *one* type that the result can be - so that's the type of the expression.

As for your broader problem - it's not clear to me that using `dynamic` would particularly help you. You may want to declare a base interface for `IHelper<T>` - a non-generic interface, that is only ever used for actual `IHelper<T>` instances. Then you can have a `List<IHelper>` where every element is *actually* an `IHelper<T>` for some `T`, but with `T` varying across instances. The `IHelper` interface isn't really *required* here, although if your `IHelper<T>` interface really contains other members which don't use `T`, those could be moved to `IHelper` instead. However, just having it for clarity can be useful.

Now, when you need to use a specific `IHelper`, *then* dynamic typing could briefly be useful. You can declare a generic method, and let dynamic typing figure out the type argument at execution time. For example:

```
private readonly IList<IHelper> helpers;

...

public void UseHelpers()
{
    foreach (dynamic helper in helpers)
    {
        UseHelper(helper); // Figures out type arguments itself
    }
}

private void UseHelper<T>(IHelper<T> helper)
{
    // Now you're in a generic method, so can use T appropriately
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, that clarifies cast vs dynamic.  I actually need to manage a collection of IEnumerable<T> returned from the IHelper<T> instances, which are later used to populate properties of new class instances (via reflection).  However, your suggestion gives me a couple more ideas; I'll try those and will post a new question with more detail if I run into issues.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Jon Skeet's answer I think you can do something really interesting and avoid the dynamic keyword because it has a performance impact.

Use `IHelper<T> : IHelper`. Now you can store the helpers like into a `List<IHelper>`. Now you could call the Foo method by maping types to a generic method.

```
public IEnumerable<T> UseHelper<T> (IHelper<T> helper)
{

}

delegate IEnumerable<object> UseHelperDelegate(IHelper helper)
Dictionary<Type, UseHelperDelegate> helpersMap;

helpersMap.Add(typeof(int), UseHelper<int>); // Add others if you want

public IEnmerable<object> UseHelperWithMap(IHelper helper)
{
    Type helperType = helper.GetType();
    IEnumerable<object> retValue;
    if (helpersMap.Contains(helperType))
    {
         retValue = helpersMap[helperType](helper);
    }
    else // if the type is not maped use DLR
    {
         dynamic dynamicHelper = helper;
         retValue = UseHelper(dynamicHelper)
         // I wonder if this can actually be added to the map here
         // to improve performance when the same type is called again.
    }
}
```

Note: you can cast `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` to `IEnumerable<object>` and `UseHelper<SomeClass>` to `UsehelperDelegate` because of [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).

Edit: It turns out you can actualy create a new concrete function from the generic and add it to the map. This way you can avoid using `dynamic`.

```
var useHelperGeneric = this.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(
               m=> m.IsGenericMethod && m.Name == "UseHelper");
var useHelper = useHelperGeneric.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { helper.GetType() });
var newFunction = (UserHelperDelegate)useHelper.MakeDelegate(typeof(UseHelperDelegate));

helpersMap.Add(helper.GetType(), newFunction);

newFunction(helper);
```

Comment: I would go for simple code before "clever" code. This may well not be the performance bottleneck - and dynamic typing has some pretty smart caching already.